# How to put bookmark onto slider while timeline marking in c#/xaml metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have checked  [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Media-Playback-003619be) sample. It shows me TimeLineMarker API. Now when I press button "Add Marker" at that time markers are added and text block shows the markers, on which time it was added. Now I want to display those markers onto Slider control in the form of any sign like any shape or whatever, so when I want to go directly onto the marker I can go directly clicking on slider. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got answer from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/6d011897-6145-40dc-be8e-b0b6e88eec09/), thanks Matt

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
         <Grid>
            <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=MySlider, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=MySlider, Path=ActualHeight}" Background="BlueViolet"/>
             <Slider x:Name="MySlider" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="750" Height="50" Loaded="MySlider_Loaded_1"/>
         </Grid>
         <Button Content="Set marker" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
     </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
int UniqueId = 0;
List<CustomTick> MyCustomTicks = new List<CustomTick>();
Thumb MySliderThumb;
Point ThumbCurrentPoint;
private void MySlider_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement templateRoot = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild((Slider)sender, 0) as FrameworkElement;
    MySliderThumb = templateRoot.FindName("HorizontalThumb") as Thumb;
}
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MySliderThumb.TransformToVisual(MyCanvas).TryTransform(new Point(0, 0), out ThumbCurrentPoint);
    CustomTick MyCustomTick = new CustomTick();
    MyCustomTick.X = ThumbCurrentPoint.X;
    MyCustomTick.Y = ThumbCurrentPoint.Y;
    MyCustomTick.Value = MySlider.Value;
    MyCustomTick.ID = UniqueId++;
    MyCustomTicks.Add(MyCustomTick);
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle MyRectangle = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle();
    MyRectangle.Name = MyCustomTick.ID.ToString();
    MyRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
    MyRectangle.Width = MySliderThumb.ActualWidth;
    MyRectangle.Height = MySliderThumb.ActualHeight;
    MyRectangle.PointerPressed += MyRectangle_PointerPressed;
    MyCanvas.Children.Add(MyRectangle);
    Canvas.SetTop(MyRectangle, MyCustomTick.Y - MyRectangle.Height );
    Canvas.SetLeft(MyRectangle, MyCustomTick.X);
}
void MyRectangle_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle MyRectangle = sender as Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle;
    CustomTick MyCustomTick = new CustomTick();
    foreach (CustomTick CT in MyCustomTicks)
    {
if (CT.ID.ToString() == MyRectangle.Name)
{
    MyCustomTick = CT;
    break;
}
    }
    MySlider.Value = MyCustomTick.Value;
}

List<CustomTick> MyTicks = new System.Collections.Generic.List<CustomTick>();
private class CustomTick
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Value;
    public int ID;
}
```